# dynamically distribute values into 3 tags

Tags: php, jquery, oracle

I have some programming problem now. What I am trying to do is dynamically allocate a value into 3 input tags. so the basic idea is the sum of those 3 inputs should not exceed the value given.

so my code is like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var 
        total = parseInt($('#quantityRequired').text()),
        inputs = $('input[type="number"]');

        inputs
            .attr('max', total)
            .change(function() {

        //Make sure that current value is in range
        if($(this).val() > parseInt($(this).attr('max'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
        } else if ($(this).val() < parseInt($(this).attr('min'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
        }

        //Get currently available total
        var current = available();

        //Now update max on each input
        $('input').each(function(indx) {
            $(this).attr('max',  parseInt($(this).val()) + total - current);
        }); 
    });

    function available() {
        var sum = 0;
        inputs.each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        return sum;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$projectName    = strval($_GET['project']); 
$thicknessValue = intval($_GET['thicknessValue']);
$baseplateValue = strval($_GET['baseplateValue']);

$query = "SELECT QTY_REQUIRED, QTY_CUT FROM COMPONENT
                WHERE THICKNESS = :thicknessVal 
                AND PROJECT_NAME = :projectName
                AND BASE_PLATE = :baseplateVal
                AND REQUEST_STATUS = 'OPEN'";

$result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":projectName", $projectName);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":thicknessVal", $thicknessValue);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ":baseplateVal", $baseplateValue);

oci_execute($result);
?>

<?php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){

$qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CUT'];   
       echo '<span id="quantityRequired">'.$qtyAvailable.'</span>';

       echo '<input id="cncQty"    name="cncQty"    type="number" min="0" value="0"   placeholder="CNC" required>';         
       echo '<input id="scatorQty" name="scatorQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="SCATOR" required>';       
       echo '<input id="manualQty" name="manualQty" type="number" min="0" value="0" placeholder="MANUAL" required>';
       echo '<br/>';      
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So all of this code here will be displayed in the div section of the other html file. 
The problem with my code is, the jquery doesn't work when it is displayed in the div. I tried it in jsfilddle and the jquery code works well.

and the jsfiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/k2QVV/

but when I apply it in the php code. it doesn't work. what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is the file extension .php or .html? The server will not execute code by default contained in a .html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running before the page is rendered, so things like:

```
inputs = $('input[type="number"]');
```

Won't find anything.

To fix this, wrap all your javascript other than the `available` function in a jQuery ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

Comment: OK, I tried to wrap it but it seems the jquery still doesn't work.

Comment: only this, TypeError: $(...).combobox is not a function
 

$( "#combobox" ).combobox();

Comment: That's not from code in the question. Can you post all the code or at least the part that tries to call `combobox`?

Comment: When you get the error in the console, does it tell you what file/line it is coming from? Usually it is all the way to the right of the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54892/discussion-between-chriskonz-and-gwcoffey).